# What would it take to rebuild an appliance for 120v

Tags: voltage

I want to purchase an appliance (it's a shirt ironing machine called a Tubie) that is made in Germany. It is designed to work with the 250v electrical system used there.  The appliance is, basically, a heating coil and a blower fan attached to an inflatable torso.  Would it be possible to replace components in this appliance in order to make it work on our power system here in the US?  If so, what would that entail?

Comment: It would be much easier and safer (and probably much cheaper!) to find a transformer with an appropriate turns ratio and power rating.

Comment: Hmm, I just a quick look around, and they are actually pretty costly.  How much power does the Tubie use?

Comment: @bitsmack there are two models with either 3320 Watt or 1920 Watt, 220V or 230V/50Hz.

Comment: If you do use a transformer(110:220), keep in mind that the 110 side is going to draw double the current as Kevin stated. This means 17~30Amps, which not many outlets in a home are going to be able to provide. This may present a hazard depending on how well your house is wired.

Comment: The "get an adapter" aspect belongs in diy.se.  The "modify" aspect belongs in electronics.se.

Comment: The answer is not to get an adapter, but to recognize that 220/230/240 volt service is already available in the US for high-power loads, both domestic (ovens, A/C) and industrial.

Answer (score 3):

This could be done without modifying the Tubie.  There are two primary considerations:

**Power consumption:**

The power consumption is greater than what is typically supported by residential wiring in the USA.  Our receptacles are generally rated to 15A @ 120V, which is 1800 Watt.  There are homes with 20A outlets and wiring, which can provide 2400W, but this is less common.

As you said in your comments, the two options are 1920W or 3320W. So even if you bought a transformer you couldn't source enough power through a standard outlet. And transformers that can handle this amount of power are hundreds of dollars.

This can be overcome if you use a 240V outlet.  If you have an electric laundry dryer, this is 240V.  Perhaps you have an additional 240V receptacle already wired in your garage or basement.  In this case you wouldn't need any sort of transformer; you could plug right in to the outlet.  240V is close enough to 230V rating as to not cause problems.

**Mains frequency**:

A second issue is that we have 60 Hz AC instead of the intended 50 Hz.  This won't effect the heater or power consumption.  But it will likely affect the fan!  Perhaps the only difference is that it will run slightly faster.  But it may also be more prone to overheating or stalling.

If it turns out that the fan has problems, it is quite inexpensive to buy a small 240V-120V transformer that would only support the fan.

Fianlly, it is possible that the timing circuitry is based on the AC frequency, but this is getting to be pretty uncommon.

Comment: I realize this isn't diy.se, but there are code issues with using an appliance designed and corded for less than 30A in a 30A circuit.  Also dryer plugs are not made for repeated plug/unplug, especially if they are the inherently unsafe NEMA 10-30 type.   That type is still allowed in legacy installations on a "let sleeping dogs lie" basis since dryers are rarely ever moved.  Plug-swapping on a regular basis defeats that last thread of safety theater.

Comment: Very good points, @Harper.  I wasn't considering it an appliance, and so the under-sized cordage didn't strike me as a problem.  Is there a preferred 240V receptacle that the NEC treats similarly to a standard NEMA 5-15? __Edit__: Oh, never mind, I just read your answer!

Answer (score 3):

Just what I was afraid of.  That unit **cannot run on** USA 120V/15A mains at full performance.  It takes too much power.

Those units come in 2 ratings: 3320 watts (3200W heater) and 1920W (1800W heater).

[image]

See the problem?  All 4 American outlets are equally easy to install, but most people install the left two everywhere.  Remember to knock off 20% for *continuous use*, so that's 1440W, 1920W, 2880W and 3840W respectively.

And by the way, to the Europeans who say "Oh, America has so many plug types" -- sure, they exist, but we have **only one in common use** on the continent and a bit of South America. As long as your appliance fits into the plug on the left, you're all set.

---

Your best bet is to use the machine unmodified.   Change the Euro plug to a NEMA 6-15 or 6-20 plug and outfit your house with NEMA 6 receptacles in your use locations.

This requires adding a 2-pole breaker to your box ( they make duplex breakers if you don't have room) and I suggest going GFCI due to wet clothes.

---

If you really, *really* want to hack it to run on 120V service, you will need to make a design decision of whether to go for NEMA 5-15 or NEMA 5-20.

You can use a 120/240 step-up transformer for fan and controls.  You'll have to find a way to center-tap the heating element.  If you are lucky, the manufacturer will have provided an easy way.  One option is to use half the heater and it will run at half power.  Do not use less than half the heater. If you use more, power will be reduced.  Another option is to fold the heater in half (put neutral on the ends, hot in the middle) and run at full power.   Or you could tear the heater out and replace it with the guts from a US domestic heater, hair dryer, heat gun etc. Total up the wattage you are using, and fit the appropriate NEMA 5-15 or 5-20 plug. Check your work with a Kill-a-Watt.

But I fear the machine may not be able to do its thing with a weakened heater.  You could hack it all up only to discover it doesn't work like it did, and then wish you had just gone 240.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, both the heater and the blower motor are simply built for 240 volts.

- The heater will be made of a particular length of wire designed to have a specific resistance. If you supply 120 volts to it, you will get a *quarter* of the intended heat output.

  If the machine happens to be built with two heating elements in series, then you *could* rewire them to be in parallel and get the right result.
- The motor will also have wiring specifically for 240 (230, 250, whatever) volts. Here it's more complicated than just the resistance, because motors have magnetic parts and interact with the mechanical load attached, but the wiring is just as specific.

  Some types of motors can be *rewound* (remove the old wire and wind new wire, but keep the mechanical and magnetic components) but it may or may not be practical to disassemble the motor in this way, and you need to understand motor design to make the proper new windings.

It might be possible to *replace* both the heater and the motor if they are separable units and not designed as part of the frame of the unit, or permanently fixed to it, but again you can't bet on that, and it would probably require metalworking to adapt the mountings.

Finally, in any case, doing this requires replacing the rest of the wiring (power cord and so on) with wire suitable for carrying the doubled input *current*.

And that current would be pretty high, though not infeasible: 17 amps for the low-power version, or *30 amps* for the “standard version” ([specs](http://tubie.de/en/ironing_machine_tubie_specifications/)). 17 amps is high enough that you'd properly be using the special 20-amp plug, if your house even has any of that type of outlet (it would have one hole in a T-shape to accept the plug), and a 20-amp or higher circuit.

---

I think that if you want to do this, the most practical option would be to **use a 240-volt outlet in your house.** All US homes have 240 volt service (it is used for appliances like electric stoves and dryers), so if there isn't an outlet already you can have one installed (unless you can't because you rent or something). You would still need an adapter for the device's power plug, or to remove the plug and install a matching one.

I thought that a clothes dryer outlet would be suitable, but according to commenter [Harper](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/95888/harper), there are code restrictions on that type, and you should use a NEMA 6-15 or 6-20 outlet instead (which are also intended for 240 volts).

Comment: For that kind of casual plug-in use, don't install a dryer plug with all the special rules.  Just install a somewhat common NEMA 6-15 or 6-20 receptacle (or a string of them, if you like).  They install just like common NEMA 5’s - you can even get duplex receptacles.  6-20 uses the same size plug, receptacle and wall plate as normal 5-20’s, and is rated for repeated casual plug-ins.